# remapping additional mouse buttons to multimedia keys

Tags: mouse, button, keys

So, I bought a new mouse, and it has 4 additional buttons (2 thumb buttons, and scrollwheel left/right) and I was wondering, since my PC doesn't have multimedia keys, can I remap those buttons to play, pause, next and previous keys??

Answer (score 0):

Some mouse buttons may trigger keyboard codes. Check if that you can configure them in the Keyboard->Shortcut menu.

[image: shortcut]